# Fancy Indexing using two criterias

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector and I would like to select all odd numbered indexed entries union with first and last entry of vector. For sake of example, let the vector:

```
v = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

I would like to do some selection that returns the elements:

```
v[someindexing]
```

returns

```
(0,1,3,5,6)
```

I did in this way:

```
mask = [0] + list(range(1,len(x)-1,2)) + [-1]
x[mask]
```

It works, but, is there a more pythonic or clean way to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is to construct the index using `np.r_` as:

```
np.r_[0,1:len(v)-1:2,-1]
```

---

```
v = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])

v[np.r_[0,1:len(v)-1:2,-1]]
# array([0, 1, 3, 5, 6])
```